# How to display the current live wallpaper inside an application?

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

How do you display the user's live wallpaper inside your application? Since live wallpapers are more than just videos, I am unsure as to where to start on this one, but I do know that it is [possible](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en).